# Should I update my program from C to modern C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

I have an old program written in C from the 1990's.  I would like to update it so that it will work for the next persons and on modern compilers.  Currently I am using a really old version of TurboC to make changes.  Should I be focusing on rewriting this in modern C or C++?  Which will be the easiest to bring this code up to date without having to rewrite too much and be able to reuse most of the existing code?

My programming background has mostly been in hprogramming languages like Perl, Python, PHP, Powershell, and Visual Basic, so I am not too familiar with the differences between C and C++.

Comment: I think the answer must depend mainly on who will be taking over.

Comment: It could be YOU! :)  For now, I have no idea who would be taking over, but this is a long term project that I would like to continue maintaining.  I want to make it straight forward and understandable for the next people 5-years from now.

Comment: If your goal is to make your program amenable to future development by other programmers, then yes, I would suggest migrating it to C++ with a modern compiler.  However, I would strongly suggest you do it in stages, with stage #1 being where you should stop migrating and leave future updates to folks who WANT to use more modern C++/STL features:  Stage #1 - Simply migrate the files to a modern compiler, fixing build warnings/errors as necessary to get it to build, then check for correct operation.  Don't begin using classes or STL or templates yet.  Stage #2 - Begin using C++ features slowly.

Comment: phonetagger: I am currently at stage #1 using Visual Studio 2010 and transitioning over to C++. I am copying over the functions, building and fixing warnings and errors, and checking for correct operation.  I just pray that the existing code works the same in C++.  For example, is "printf" in C really the same as "printf" in C++?  :)  That's when I stopped to ask this question and wondered if I am on the right track or not.

Answer (score 5):

C and C++ are different languages, not different versions of the same language. Stick to C, although you could use the fancy features of newer versions of the standard, like C99.

Answer (score 5):

Your last sentence pretty much answers your sentiment. If you aren't familiar with the differences and you only know older languages I wouldn't update this program unless there is something horribly wrong with it that is affecting many users.

You could update it just within the C world to adhere to C99 or C11 if you have a newer compiler

Comment: If it was me, I'd like C++ as I think in OO and like having native support. If you asked Linus Torvalds on the other hand, you'd get a totally different response: http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/linus. I'd be hard-pressed to say I was a better developer, or that the Linux kernel is not modern... :-)

Comment: @Alex try writing, porting and optimizing low-level code for a driver or some OS facility in C++, then come back and we'll talk again :P ;)

Comment: @menis As it happens, I have for a couple of embedded platforms. But it wasn't pretty. And it was a pretty restricted subset of C++... ;-)

Comment: @Alex so you see his point, right? ;)

Comment: @mensi, sigh, while for some parts of an embedded platform you should certainly restrict the subset used (this actually even is the case for C), but really, C++ is perfectly usable for embedded development (I know there are several network OS's written mainly in C++)

Answer (score 3):

Given:

have an old program written in C from the 1990's.

You have two questions:

Should I be focusing on rewriting this in modern C?
Maybe, maybe not.  I would try to adhere to a standard C89, C99, or C11.  This mainly depends on your tools and how much new development will happen.

Do you like declaring variables other than at the beginning of scope?  If so, then possibly update to C99.  Are you using any tools that really like C89 and show errors or warnings with C99 conventions?  If so, then stick to C89.

If the program is continually being updated and you are hiring young people, then newer conventions might be beneficial.

Should I be focusing on rewriting this in C++?
No.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I am not familiar with the different C standards, but I assume that C89, C99, and C11 standards, are here to stay for the long run?  Do you have any suggestions off the top of your head for a modern C compiler that supports those various C89, C99, or C11, standards?

Comment: gcc and Visual Studio are options.  Note that C++ compilers will compile C code and I think under the hood, most of the current C compilers are actually C++ compilers by default.  However, with Visual Studio (and probably gcc), you can specify to compile files as C++ or as C.  I don't know anything about your application, so I don't know what IDE/compiler features you would want.  If you are doing plain C that only gets executed from the command prompt, then TurboC may be the best choice until you a real need to change.

Answer (score 3):

Most well-written C programs are also valid C++ programs, or require just a little adaptation. The opposite is not true.

It's probably easier to stick with ANSI/ISO C and leave both doors open for the next maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably about the same effort to move to a modern C compiler vs. a modern C++ compiler. The evolution of C and C++ have diverged where each has similar features but they're not source compatible.

There are a few factors that would lead me to choose to update to C++:

- Modern C doesn't seem to enjoy as much support as C++. For example many new things in C seem to get implemented only as required by C++, especially in the Microsoft world. VS doesn't even support C99 except for what's in C++, let alone C11.
- [C++ is a better C](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html#difference): "C++ is "a better C" in the sense that it supports the styles of programming done using C with better type checking and more notational support (without loss of efficiency)." This is still true of modern versions of C.
- C++ adds features that support some very powerful techniques. Really making use of them may be best left to library developers, but that means C++ can support really great libraries.